# Код из node.js в PHP

Tags: php, node.js

Подскажите как этот код на PHP написать?

Мне нужно только массив баланса получить с одной криптобиржи

```
curl -u "apiKey:secretKey" https://api.hitbtc.com/api/3/spot/balance
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.auth = ("apiKey", "secretKey")

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const credentials = Buffer.from('apiKey' + ':' + 'secretKey').toString('base64');

fetch('https://api.hitbtc.com/api/3/spot/balance', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
define(API_URL, "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/3/spot/balance");
$credentials = bae64_encode("$apiKey:$secretKey");

$opts = [
     'http' => [
         'header' => "Authorization: Basic $credentials\r\n"
     ]
  ];
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents(API_URL, false, $ctx);
$result = json_decode($reponse);
```

или так

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, API_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic $credentials"]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_encode($response);
```